# How to use profile to authenticate and apply terraform file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to be able deploy some script files to aws lambda using a terraform file.

Here is a my file:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "0.11.7"
}

variable "region" {}


provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"
  version = "2.00"
}



// Zip the scripts folder (thus creating a package) before supplying it to the lambda function.
data "archive_file" "package_zip" {
  type = "zip"
  source_dir = "${path.root}/scripts/"  # Path from top level module.
  output_path = "./sources.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "anthony_test_lambda" {
  filename      = "lambda_function_payload.zip"
  function_name = "anthony_test_lambda"
  role          = "new-role"
  handler       = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"

  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.package_zip.output_base64sha256}"

  runtime = "python3.7"


}
```

I want to keep the script as flexible as possible because I may not the only one who will work on the script in the future.

I want to be able to drive the process by using AWS profile. Here is what I tried:

```
 export AWS_PROFILE=a_team
 tf apply
```

I got this error:

```
* provider.aws: No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider.
    Please see https://terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html for more information on
    providing credentials for the AWS Provider
```

I cannot use AWS access key id and secret.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a possible problem with the AWS_PROFILE environment variable, make sure AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID are unset. This will ensure that the keys which it is taking via the environment variable is from AWS_PROFILE environment variable.

Refer the Environment Variable section under https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html article for how to set the environment variables for your secret and access keys.